# Set "val" not working(pre selecting)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have looked at multiple questions on SO and on Git hub:

- [Set multiple Select2 options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21087735/2173793)
- [Select2 can't set multiple value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24905607/2173793)
- [Is initSelection used for select2(val)](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/224)

But I still cant seem to figure out why the values is not being set.

I am using a jinja2 template, so Ill give the generated html/js:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="message_type">Meassage Type</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="hidden" name="message_type" id="message_type" readonly />
    </div>
</div>
```

and the js:

```
$(function () {
    $("#message_type").select2({
        placeholder: "Email/SMS/PIMS Modal",
        multiple: true,
        width: "300px",
        tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
        data: [{
            id: "email",
            text: "Email"
        }, {
            id: "pims modal",
            text: "PIMS Modal"
        }, {
            id: "sms",
            text: "SMS"
        }, ],
    });

    $("#message_type").select2("val", "pims modal");

});
```

I have also managed to reproduce the result, see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/renierdebruyn/nww22qoj/4/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurs because you have set the `multiple` property to true. In this case to set a value you need to use an array instead of a string.

For example:

```
$(function () {
    $("#message_type").select2({
        placeholder: "Email/SMS/PIMS Modal",
        multiple: true,
        width: "300px",
        tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
        data: [{
            id: "email",
            text: "Email"
        }, {
            id: "pims modal",
            text: "PIMS Modal"
        }, {
            id: "sms",
            text: "SMS"
        }, ],
    });

    $("#message_type").select2("val", ["email"]);
});
```

A working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/nww22qoj/19/

**Edit**: Here is a working jsfiddle using the 4.0.1 version of the plugin http://jsfiddle.net/nww22qoj/20/ (*using the full version of the plugin*)

Comment: This does not seem to work in ASP.net MVC with select2 4.0.0

Comment: @JpHouten I provided a second jsfiddle for the new version of the plugin, hope this helps

Comment: @TasosK. Thank you, thanks to you and help here: https://github.com/select2/select2-bootstrap-theme/issues/30#issuecomment-166004971 I found the solution :)

Comment: @TasosK. wrong link, it should be: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4035